# JPA returns multiple times the same entity (bidirectional OneToMany)

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have a problem with such a straight forward topic (i thought this couldnt be such a problem, but DB/persistens is not my favourite one actually).

Consider the following Classes:

```
Class Parent {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<Child> getChilds() {..}
}

Class Child {

    @ManyToOne
    public getParent(){..}

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "child", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<GrandChild> getGrandChilds() {..}
}

Class GrandChild {

    @ManyToOne
    public getChild(){..}
}
```

Now in initservice:

```
Parent p = new Parent();
List<Child> cl = new ArrayList<Child>();

Child c1 = new Child();
c1.setParent(p);
List<GrandChild> gcl1 = new ArrayList<GrandChild>();
c1.setGrandChilds(gcl1);

Child c2 = new Child();
c2.setParent(p);
List<GrandChild> gcl2 = new ArrayList<GrandChild>();

GrandChild gc1 = new GrandChild();
gc1.setChild(c2);
gcl2.add(gc1);
GrandChild gc2 = new GrandChild();
gc2.setChild(c2);
gcl2.add(gc2);

c2.setGrandChilds(gcl2);

cl.add(c1);
cl.add(c2);
p.setChilds(cl);
Parent tmp1 = parentDao.save(p);
```

**tmp1** contains a childlist of 2 elements (c1 and c2)

But if i get the parent from the DAO, the list (actually its a bag?!) contains 3 elements! (c1, c2, c2)

What am i missing? Do i have to change the CascadeType for the child, actually i dont really understand the Cascadetypes.

*EDIT:*
In the DB it looks as it should be.

1 Parent

2 Childs with parent 1

2 Grandchilds with the same child

*EDIT2*: removed irrelevant codeline:

```
gcl2.add(new GrandChild());
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `gcl2.add(new GrandChild());`? It will create a parentless `GrandChild` since `Grandchild.child` is not set

Comment: Sorry, my bad. That was just a copy-paste mistake!